# Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

Hello I'm a new user of ubuntu and i can't figure out how to install and where to get the right driver for my Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT hardware. The version of ubuntu that i have is 12.04 and at the moment my resolution is very low and i'd like to have the resolution i had on windows

Comment: very few times when i restart the pc the resolution goes normal again, so i think it might be a setting problem

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to open "system settings" (that's the icon on the left which resembles a gear and a wrench).  Once there click on Additional Drivers.  Ubuntu will take several minutes seeking drivers for any devices which could be better supported.  It might decide some other component needs better support before it gets around to your graphics card.

Comment: sorry but i've been away for awhile. anyways i already tried to do what yo said but it still doesn't work.